Connecting two pieces of AC drain line with vinyl tubing
I recently modified my drain line and ended up twisting it more than intended when gluing the PVC sections back together. As a result, my outdoor drain is no longer straight and looks unsightly. To fix this, I can make another cut near the end of the indoor section and use a coupling to adjust the direction of the outdoor section.
I watched a YouTube video where a technician used vinyl tubing (I believe it was 1-inch inner diameter) to connect AC drains. I think this approach is neat because it would allow for easier modifications in the future (just in case this happens again); I wouldn't need to worry about adding another coupling to straighten the outside piece.
Would this be a good practice? Are there any potential issues?


I've done that for years. Those drain lines will often get clogged and won't drain resulting in water backing up and shutting down your unit if equiped with a float switch and /or leaking water all over the place. The tubing makes for an easy fix to attach a hose to and blow out the clog. Have at it.

Could you please explain how to slide it in? It looks easy in the video, but when I tried it, it was very tight and nearly impossible.

If you have a bit of clear tubing, you can also use that as a visual check to confirm that the drain is open and condensation is still running.  The tubing might slip on more easily better if you make sure there aren't any burrs or protrusions on the PVC end (a bit of sandpaper will help make sure it's a smooth end) and slightly warm the clear tubing with a hair dryer to make it temporarily softer and more flexible.

@Chris   A little plumber's grease or vaseline might help to. Don't insert it too far. It's just a gravity drain so doesn't have much pressure.
